# How to sum times in java

Tags: java

I have this string:

```
String times = "5:15 | 4:41 | 4:27 | 3:13 | 5:01 | 4:47 | 4:50 | 5:20"
```

The result should be "37:34"

How do I handle this in java string and return the expected result?

Comment: It strikes me that there are three separate tasks here: parsing the strings into some time-related type; summing the time-related values; formatting the result. We don't know how far you've got with any of those.

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating DateTime variables and summing them is an approach, but I assume you're new to Java and give you basic answer to warn you up for some coding and not to go the easy way:

```
String[] timesSplit = times.split(" | ");

int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < timesSplit.length; i += 2) {
    String[] time = timesSplit[i].split(":");
    hour += Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
    minute += Integer.parseInt(time[1]);
}

hour += minute / 60;
minute %= 60;

String result = hour + ":" + minute;
```

EDIT: Strange behaviour, splitting for " | " results String array like:

`5:33, |, 1:32, ..`

So edited the for increment statement accordingly. You can check the running code [here](http://ideone.com/xrpzIX).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a tokenizer to parse this string.
Iterate over the resulting `Array`, take *hours* and *minutes* of all values and add them (h+h and min+min). When you have done calculate:

```
hours += minutes / 60
minutes = minutes % 60
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the Strings and convert all to minutes. Than add them and convert it back to hour and minutes.